# Consuming ColdFusion RESTful Service

Tags: web-services, rest, extjs, datagrid, coldfusion

I created a Rest Service with ColdFusion. It returns an xml file or json like this:

```
<query id ='1'>
<columnnames>
   <COLUMN NAME="Name">
   <COLUMN NAME="Surname">
</columnnames>
<ROW>
<COLUMN TYPE="STRING">...</COLUMN>
<COLUMN TYPE="STRING">...</COLUMN>
</ROW>
```

or

```
{"COLUMNS":["Name","Surname"],"DATA":[["...","..."]
```

Is there anyone that can explain how I can parse this data into a grid with ExtJS or another javascript framework?

This is my cfc:

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="/hello">
    <cffunction name="query" returntype="query" access="remote" produces="application/json" httpmethod="GET">
        <cfquery name="myQuery" datasource="dbrc">
            SELECT Name, Surname
            FROM TBUSERS
            LIMIT 10
        </cfquery>
        <cfreturn myQuery>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: Are you sure about your service returning xml or json?  It looks to me that you are returning a query, or at least trying to.  Your function tag does not have a returnType attribute and the documention states that it's mandatory for web services.

Comment: When i change the produces attribute in application/json my service return a file like this: {"COLUMNS":["Name","Surname"],"DATA":[["...","..."] ------ When i change it in application/xml it return this <query id ='1'>
<columnnames>
   <COLUMN NAME="Name">
   <COLUMN NAME="Surname">
</columnnames>
<ROW>
<COLUMN TYPE="STRING">...</COLUMN>
<COLUMN TYPE="STRING">...</COLUMN>
</ROW>

Comment: @DanBracuk that's the correct JSON representation for a query object. There are two, but this is the default. Its kind of handy for quick and dirty stuff, but always best to build your own JSON for clarity and ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked using at the JSONReader in extjs or jQuery.getJSON function?

**NOTE :** 
Despite the fact that the web service was created using ColdFusion, this is a javascript/ext.js question and not a ColdFusion question.

Comment: Yes but i'm not sure that i'm on the right way. I've seen some json file with a different structure. is mine rappresentation correct?

Comment: The representation is correct for the object you are returning. If you want to appear some other way then you need to use a different return type and build your own json. http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/10/5/Neat-little-ColdFusion-10-REST-Trick might help.

Answer (score 0):

returntype="any" produces="application/json"

in the api cfcomponent is what I used to return the query results in json format

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="restService" produces="application/json">
```

I can't tell if returnformat="JSON" in the cffunction tag does anything for the api being returned in json.

```
<cffunction name="test" access="remote" returnformat="JSON" returntype="any" httpmethod="GET" >
```